# LWC Playground: Save option removed?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-playground

Did Salesforce get rid of the Save button in Lightning Web Component Playground?

I [can't find anything in the release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/search?query=playground&version=summer20) about this.  Pretty unfortunate if this is permanent.  Saved Playground examples have been a key tool supporting StackExchange discourse on the LWC framework and LWC base components.

[image: The Playground, sans Save]

Worth noting -- when you click the Help icon, a reference to the Save functionality is still there:

[image]

But on Ctrl+S, you get this:

[image]

Comment: Since I am coming here frequently through google, and all docs removed the references, I quickly wanted to pin the (only?) currently available playground for lwc: https://webcomponents.dev/workspace/lwc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Salesforce has removed option to save and download playground projects from July 22nd. This is documented in lwc documentation log.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_change_log

It is also that existing saved projects will be deleted on December 1st, so start taking backup on your own.

To make backup easier, salesforce has created a CLI extension to export the saved projects easily.

https://twitter.com/brianmfear/status/1286303953215397889?s=19

https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-playground-export#usage

Comment: +1 though the time to recover the saved items has been extended to Dec 1st.

Comment: It really sucks though - how much was it costing them to host a few code snippets?

Comment: If the playground LWC behaviour was identical to on-platform behaviour I would 100% agree that this loss is a blow to community collaboration. However, I have found too many differences in behaviour to trust the playground and therefore do not value it and do not really mourn the loss of saved projects and URL based sharing.